# Is there difference between Cache index address calculation vs Division hash function?

Tags: caching, data-structures, hash, cpu-architecture

Upon studying hash data structure and cache memory from computer architecture, I noticed that they're very similar.

Division hash function calculates index by hash(k) = k Mod (table size M) but my DS book says M should be a prime number or at least an odd number, because if M is an even number, the result is always even when k is even, odd when k is odd, so even M should be avoided since you often use memory addresses which are always even.

And yet, my CA book says for direct-mapped cache you use (Block address) Mod (Number of blocks in the cache) and the result indices look uniform. Why is this? It's all very confusing because MIPS uses 32 bit address every 4 bytes which is even number. But I think it's because they threw out the last 2 bits since they're byte offsets?

And, since it uses (Block address) Mod (Number of blocks in the cache), it makes the cache size power of 2 so that you can just use the lower x bits of the block address.

**But this method looks exactly the same as division hash function, except you make the hash table power of 2, which is even (data structure book said use prime or odd) and use the lower bits of the block address.**

Are these 2 different methods? If so, what's the cache one called? I would really appreciate a reply please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not using an even number for hash table is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102625/why-only-use-primes-for-hash-function-division-method).
And how caches use addresses to calculate line numbers are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893097/how-do-i-map-a-memory-address-to-a-block-when-there-is-an-offset-in-a-direct-map). And its ok for caches to map more than one entry to the same line. Just because an address is mapped to a cacheline which has data, we don't blindly use the data in that cacheline. We also do a tag comparison to make sure that the content is the cacheline is what exactly we are looking for.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. irrelevant, and the first link is totally wrong. That happens because you used M which is bigger than the key value. It has to be smaller so the lower bits can be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using a prime to take the modulo by is to get "mixing" of the bits, which is helpful if the integers that you're hashing have a poor structure. That isn't the only way to deal with it though, and for example the Java standard library doesn't use that, it uses a separate "mixing" function (that XORs the input with right-shifted versions of itself) and then uses a power-of-two sizes table. Either way it's protection against badly distributed input, which isn't necessary in and of itself - if the input was always nicely distributed you wouldn't need it.

Memory addresses are usually fairly nicely distributed, because it's typically used in sequential pieces. The obvious exception is that you will see highly aligned big objects, which would conflict with each other in the cache if nothing was done about it. Of course you will probably use a set-associative cache rather than direct mapped, since it is far more robust against degradation, and that would take care of a lot of that. But nothing is ever immune to bad patterns (that also goes for hash-mod-prime, which you can easily defeat if you know the prime), but a fairly simple improvement (which is also used in practice, or at least was, more advanced techniques exist now - combined with adaptive replacement strategies that mitigate bad access patterns) is to XOR some of the higher address bits into the index. This is hash-strengthening, the same technique used in the Java standard library, but a much simpler version of it.

Computing a remainder by a prime number (or really anything that isn't a power of two) is not something you'd want to do in this case, it's a slow computation by itself, and it leaves you with an awkwardly sized cache that doesn't fully use the power of its decoders, which adds to the slowness (or reduces cache size for a given latency, depending on how you look at it). The difference between that and XORing some of the high bits into the low bits is much bigger in hardware than it is in software, since XOR is really a trivial operation in hardware, much faster as a circuit operation than as an instruction.